# How to import an SPWeb using c# to have the same behavior than PowerShell?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a problem with comportment of sharepoint.deployment.spimport.

I want to copy a web within the same site collection like that :

> myserver/mysitecoll/website1
>
> myserver/mysitecoll/website2

When I use the PowerShell command to execute this, it does it perfectly, the website2 is the same as the website1

```
 Export-SPWeb -Identity http://myserver/mysitecoll/website1 -Path D:\mybackups\mytestsave\mybackup.bak
```

and

```
Import-SPWeb -Identity http://myserver/mysitecoll/website2 -Path D:\mybackups\mytestsave\mybackup.bak
```

But I need to do the same with c# I use

```
    private void ExportSpWeb()
    {

        SPSite mySite = SPContext.Current.Site;
        SPWeb myWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;  
        SPExportObject exportObject = new SPExportObject();
        exportObject.Id = myWeb.ID;
        exportObject.ParentId = mySite.ID;
        exportObject.Type = SPDeploymentObjectType.Web;
        SPExportSettings settings = new SPExportSettings();
        settings.SiteUrl = mySite.Url;
        settings.ExportMethod = SPExportMethodType.ExportAll;
        settings.FileLocation = "D:\\mybackups\\mytestsave";
        settings.BaseFileName = "test.cab";
        settings.FileCompression = true;
        settings.ExcludeDependencies = true;
        settings.CommandLineVerbose = true;
        settings.ExportObjects.Add(exportObject);
        SPExport export = new SPExport(settings);
        export.Run();
    }
    private void importSpWeb()
    {
        SPSite mySite = SPContext.Current.Site;
        SPWeb myDestWeb = mySite.AllWebs["website2"];
        SPImportSettings impsettings = new SPImportSettings();
        impsettings.SiteUrl = mySite.Url;
        impsettings.LogFilePath = "D:\\mybackups\\mytestsave\\test.log";
        impsettings.WebUrl = myDestWeb.ServerRelativeUrl;
        impsettings.FileLocation = "D:\\mybackups\\mytestsave";
        impsettings.FileCompression = true;
        impsettings.BaseFileName = "test.cab";
        impsettings.RetainObjectIdentity = false;
        SPImport import = new SPImport(impsettings);
        import.Run();
    }
```

But the comportment is not the same as PowerShell : Instead of being created using the specified WebUrl setting (http://myserver/mysitecoll/website2),
the imported  website  is created as a new subsite with the path
http://myserver/mysitecoll/website2/website1

How should I edit my code to obtain the same results as PowerShell?

Comment: do my answer resolves your issue?

Comment: Hello, at first thank you  to your answer, result currently, we have made the decision to use the "site definitions", but, it may interest the SharePoint expert developer in my enterprise to have the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question got me thinking very deeply, because I hit the wall as you did, but this led me to coming up with a quesion: [Where is definition of sharepoint cmdlets and How to get their implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44294577/get-implementation-of-sharepoint-powershell-cmdlets)

So having the knowledge where `Import-SPWeb` aka `SPCmdletImportWeb` in `Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.dll` is I checked how it's done.

The tricky part is, that for some reason `SPImportWeb` has some strange logic to modify WebUrl property and always add `/` to the end. So in `SPCmdletImportWeb` they are using `SPImport` class `Created` event to reset some properties.

For your case, when you're exporting and importing one SPWeb object you need add code below to your import object:

```
string webUrl = "website2";
// your stuff
SPImport import = new SPImport(impsettings);
import.Started += delegate(object sender, SPDeploymentEventArgs args)
{
    SPImportObjectCollection rootObjects = args.RootObjects;
    if (rootObjects[0].Type == SPDeploymentObjectType.Web)
    {
        rootObjects[0].TargetParentUrl = site.Url;
        rootObjects[0].TargetName = webUrl;
        return;
    }
};
```

To look for the full code of `SPCmdletImportWeb` get [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) and follow my mini tutorial in the first url.

Full test code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_ExportSpWeb()
{
    ExportSpWeb("http://lab/sites/custom-dev", "website1", @"C:\temp\bak\bak2.bak");
}

[TestMethod]
public void Test_ImportSpWeb()
{
    ImportSpWeb("http://lab/sites/custom-dev", "website2", @"C:\temp\bak\bak2.bak");
}

private void ImportSpWeb(string siteUrl, string webUrl, string path)
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(webUrl))
    {
        SPImportSettings impsettings = new SPImportSettings();
        impsettings.SiteUrl = site.Url;
        impsettings.LogFilePath = path + ".log";
        impsettings.WebUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + webUrl;
        impsettings.FileLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        impsettings.FileCompression = true;
        impsettings.CommandLineVerbose = true;
        impsettings.BaseFileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
        impsettings.RetainObjectIdentity = false;
        SPImport import = new SPImport(impsettings);
        import.Started += delegate(object sender, SPDeploymentEventArgs args)
        {
            SPImportObjectCollection rootObjects = args.RootObjects;
            if (rootObjects[0].Type == SPDeploymentObjectType.Web)
            {
                rootObjects[0].TargetParentUrl = site.Url;
                rootObjects[0].TargetName = webUrl;
                return;
            }
        };
        import.Run();
    }
}

private void ExportSpWeb(string siteUrl, string webUrl, string path)
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(webUrl))
    {
        SPExportObject exportObject = new SPExportObject();
        exportObject.Id = web.ID;
        exportObject.ParentId = site.ID;                
        exportObject.Type = SPDeploymentObjectType.Web;
        SPExportSettings settings = new SPExportSettings();
        settings.SiteUrl = site.Url;
        settings.ExportMethod = SPExportMethodType.ExportAll;
        settings.FileLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        settings.BaseFileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
        settings.LogFilePath = path + ".log";
        settings.FileCompression = true;
        settings.ExcludeDependencies = true;
        settings.CommandLineVerbose = true;
        settings.ExportObjects.Add(exportObject);
        SPExport export = new SPExport(settings);
        export.Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: I try your answer, its work perfectly, thank you so much :)

Comment: glad that worked for you. please mark this as answered.