# Get implementation of sharepoint powershell cmdlets

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, powershell-cmdlet

How to find managed code SharePoint (whichever version) cmdlets implementations?

MSDN does not specify where and how cmdlets are implemented. There is only information how to use them. Is this done for some reason?

Comment: Become a Microsoft Employee on the appropriate team, look at the code?
 Only PowerShell 6 is open source, IIRC individual modules are up to the team that owns them and they mostly are not open source. (SharePoint, Exchange, ActiveDirectory, etc. etc.)

Comment: What's provoking the question?

Comment: check and learn - learn the tricks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I started digging…

Let’s for example take SharePoint 2013 15 Hive.

`15 Hive` folder structure explained: [SharePoint 2013: The 15 Hive and other important directories](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25431.sharepoint-2013-the-15-hive-and-other-important-directories.aspx)

**CMDLET Registration files location**

`15/Config/Powershell/Registration` folder contains XML cmdlet registration files where for given assembly there are defined list of cmdlet definitions.

**Sample XML**

```xml
<ps:Cmdlet>
    <ps:VerbName>Uninstall-SPFeature</ps:VerbName>
    <ps:ClassName>Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletUninstallFeature</ps:ClassName>
    <ps:HelpFile>Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.dll-help.xml</ps:HelpFile>
</ps:Cmdlet>
```

SharePoint cmdlets are registered in WSSCmdlet.xml (there is a lot more) and their definition Assembly is:

> Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell, Version=15.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"

Assembly is located in GAC:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

**Manged C# Code**

Using decompiler like [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) you can find exact class in DLL and get c# implementation of cmdlet.

For example

```
[SPCmdlet(RequireLocalFarmExist = true), Cmdlet("Get", "SPSiteUrl", SupportsShouldProcess = true)]
public sealed class SPCmdletGetSPSiteUrl : SPGetCmdletBase<SPSiteUrl>
{
    // implementation details irrelevant for question context
}
```

**The Tricks**

1. [How to import an SPWeb using c# to have the same behavior than PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44201669/how-to-import-an-spweb-using-c-sharp-to-have-the-same-behavior-than-powershell)